# request.js Bearer authentication not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, requestjs

Have a problem with [request/request](https://github.com/request/request) library. Bearer authentication does not seem to work.

**Expected behavior**:
Want to send an http request to heroku to get information about my dyno

**What happens**:
404 despite sending proper authentication

I have tried 2 different ways, first `Authorization` header, then `auth` option specified in [request's docs](https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication).

Below is code for both.

OPTION 1:

```
var options = {
  url: `https://api.heroku.com/apps/${process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME}/dynos,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};
```

OPTION 2:

```
var options = {
  url: `https://api.heroku.com/apps/${process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME}/dynos,
  method: 'GET',
  auth: { bearer: process.env.HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN },
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};
```

I have also tried a different, valid path with `DELETE` method, also got 404.

With Postman, both get and delete requests work like a charm (with `Authorization` header set to `Bearer ${process.env.HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN}`)

Any ideas appreciated, thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed the value of  `HEROKU_APP_NAME ` variable?

Comment: All good, was the `HEROKU_APP_NAME` variable indeed. Both of the above options work, albeit I had a wrong env variable. Thanks

Comment: @L_K feel free to submit your answer below, thanks

Comment: It's ok, glad to help ;-)